# In AzureDataFactory,Unable to embed a C# code inside pipeline

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

I  am new to Azure Data Factory. I know we can insert script/stored procedure inside Activity. How Can I embed  C# code as a activity inside a pipeline .Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can by creating a .net app and run it on Azure Batch, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity):

> you can create a Custom activity with your own data movement or transformation logic and use the activity in a pipeline. The custom activity runs your customized code logic on an Azure Batch pool of virtual machines.

Another option is to create an http triggered azure function and use the [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity). It basically allows you to call an azure function, possibly written in c#, and process the result.

Finally, you could call any REST api wherever it is hosted as long as it is publicly reachable by using the generic [web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)

Comment: Can i pass parameters as inputs to the Azure Function Activity just like passing parameters to stored procedures in adf

Comment: Kind of, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#routing-and-queries